# Uniformly update jQueryUI Progressbar over N seconds

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, progress-bar, settimeout

Given a variable N, reflecting a number of seconds, I'd like to have a jQueryUI [Progressbar](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Progressbar) smoothly update from being empty to reflecting completion over that period of time.

In other words, I'd like a `function n_sec_progressbar(n) { ... }` that shows a progressbar, and over `n` seconds the progressbar uniformly advances from a `value` of 0 to 100.

Before I go ahead and start fiddling with `setTimeout` on my own, I'd be grateful for any suggestions or direction towards something like this that's already been done.

Thank you for reading.

Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a function like this

```
(function( $ ) {
    jQuery.fn.fillProgressBar = function(option){
    var settings = jQuery.extend({
        fromValue : 0,
        toValue : 0,
        interval : 1000
    },option);

    function fillProgressBar(element,initialValue,toValue,interval){
    //  console.log("out "+initialValue);
        if(initialValue<=toValue){
        /*  $j(element).progressbar({
                value : initialValue++
            });*/
            $j(element).progressbar( "value", initialValue++ );
        //  console.log(initialValue);
            setTimeout(function(){
                fillProgressBar(element,initialValue,toValue,interval);
            }, parseInt(interval/toValue));
        //  console.log("in "+initialValue);

        }
    }
    fillProgressBar(this,settings.fromValue,settings.toValue,settings.interval);
    return this;
};})( jQuery );
```

and make calls as

```
$j("#progressBar").progressbar({
    value:0 });

$j("#progressBar").fillProgressBar({toValue : progressBarValue,
    interval : 1000});
```

Answer (score 2):

I would think it would be easier just to write your own custom progress bar using the [callback](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) of `animate()` (jQuery core API). That would give you the most control for a loading animation like that.